# how to get latest date data from table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get rows of the latest date and the next latest date. I have searched lots of sites and I have still no idea how to write the sql statement.

From this

```
id      inputDate       refNo
1       2016-09-22      16092201820X0X
2       2016-09-22      16092200230X1X
3       2016-09-22      16092200810X3X
4       2016-09-21      16092200430X2X
5       2016-09-21      16092201460X7X
6       2016-09-21      16092200430X1X
7       2016-09-20      16092202260X3X
8       2016-09-20      16092200330X6X
9       2016-09-20      16092200610X3X
10      2016-09-19      16092200430X8X
11      2016-09-19      16092200450X1X
```

to this

```
id      inputDate       refNo
1       2016-09-22      16092201820X0X
2       2016-09-22      16092200230X1X
3       2016-09-22      16092200810X3X
4       2016-09-21      16092200430X2X
5       2016-09-21      16092201460X7X
6       2016-09-21      16092200430X1X
```

Comment: Which brand/version of RDBMS database is this for?

Comment: i am using xampp, http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ for testing at home, but my work is using hibernate spring mvc. I dont know what rdbms of my work is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ANSI standard SQL, you would use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by inputdate desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

MySQL does not support the ANSI-standard window functions (unlike basically all other major databases).

In MySQL, this is trickier.  Here is a convenient method:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select inputdate
      from (select distinct inputdate from t) t
      order by inputdate desc
      limit 2
     ) tt
     on t.inputdate = tt.inputdate;
```

You don't actually need the second subquery, so you can do:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select distinct inputdate
      from t
      order by inputdate desc
      limit 2
     ) tt
     on t.inputdate = tt.inputdate;
```

But it can be confusing to remember whether `select distinct` happens before or after the `order by`.

Comment: thanks for quick response, I have tried your code but i got red line in the second select(this type of clause was previously parsed) and also the word seqnum (an alias was previously found).

Comment: @peter: you need to tell us which DBMS you are using and the **exact** error message you get when you run that statement.